# Storing results of an active record query as a hash with their id as the key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql

I am using ruby on rails with postgresql and was just wondering is there a fast way to convert an active record query into a hash with the id column as the key. I can do it using loops but its extremely slow and I guess there must be a way to do it more efficiently.

Comment: Convert a query to a hash? Do you mean to convert the results of the query to a hash or the query text itself?

Comment: Sorry the results of the query

Comment: I don't think it's possible to it other than running all the queries (in a loop). What is the use case for which you want this? If you want caching it's probably best to cache it once it has been requested once and invalidating it when related data changes. Don't this you should be implementing it yourself though ;)

Comment: Actually I want to send the results of the query has a hash and then use it in javascript in my view. And basically I could just use to_json but I have to add column to the keys which let's us know what kind of query is this. I have implemented it using a loop for now but it's slow when you have a huge query result. Basically I run two queries to find the available and unavailable drivers. I want to send the type of the driver along with all the other driver details as json